# How to use multiple API KEYs using Laravel and mandrill

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mandrill

I need to be able to send emails using `Laravel 4.2` and `Mandrill` using 2 different `API KEYs`.

I followed the following tutorial and it works great with a SIGNLE `API KEY` (the one you set in the services.php) http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail

I've tried using the following code to set different API KEYs on the fly ( as opposed to used the one in the services.php) but I had no success

How can I set a new API KEY for each time I would like to send an email?

```
App::bind('Mandrill', function()
{
    return new Mandrill('API KEY');
});
App::bindShared('swift.transport', function()
{
    return new MandrillTransport("API KEY");
});

// Sends Collection Email with the Unique Collection Code
Mail::send('emails.collect.collect', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('info@domain.com', 'mr Smith');
    $message->subject('22:24 EMAIL');
    $message->to("jonathan@mail.co.uk");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the configuration in runtime:

```
Config::set('services.mandrill.secret', 'YOUR API KEY');
```